# Running docker commands with an user without root privileges (possibly with www-data user of Apache)

Tags: apache, docker

I am developing a simple Flask application (configured with a Apache webserver) which provides a web interface for docker management. My apache server runs as ‘www-data’ user and it uses the same for all of its API operations.

But i get the ‘Permission denied’ error for the following,
docker images
docker run, etc…
as it doesnt allow ‘www-data’ user to run the above commands.

Can you please provide me a suggestion on using the ‘www-data’ user for docker operations.

I dont want to add ‘www-data’ user to sudoers list.

Is adding the user to docker group alone will be a proper solution ???

Or please suggest me a best practice solution for this.

Thanks
GuruPrasad

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier, clearer, and no less dangerous to tell Apache to [run your process as root](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/suexec.html).

Remember that, if you can run any Docker command at all, you can trivially get unrestricted root-level access to anything on the system.  For example, if your tool decides it really *does* want `www-data` to be in the host's sudoers list, it can

```
docker run --rm -v /:/host busybox \
  sh -c 'echo www-data ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL >> /host/etc/sudoers'
```

Depending on what your management tool does, it potentially is offering equal unprotected root-level access to the host to anyone who can reach the Web page.  Even if it isn't, you need to be extremely careful with how you invoke Docker (another SO answer I was looking at had the potential to root the system if a user could create a directory with an arbitrary name and run the script from there, for instance).

Comment: Hi David. In my case, the docker container itself will be launched/run through the web interface only. So the request will be through www-data user only and not through root. Also the restriction is that www-data should not be in sudoers list. Please suggest me any alternative for this.

Comment: In the question you say “a Web interface for Docker management”; what prevents me from launching a container similar to what I showed and gaining root on the system?

Comment: The very slightly more detailed answer is “it’s all Unix permissions on `/var/run/docker.sock`”; the Ubuntu default is mode 0660, owned by user `root` and group `docker`.  Since you’re running a privileged task setting your job to be runnable as `root` is appropriate, up to security concerns about what you’re actually exposing.